# Attribute Error split when trying to apply split method in flatmap after converting DF to RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using below code snippet to read some sample file using spark context

```
>>> textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/sample.txt")
>>> textFile.flatMap(lambda word:word.split(" ")).collect()
```

Assume this gives output something like below

```
[u'hi', u'there,', u'I', u'am', u'working', u'on', u'something', u'random.']
```

Now I am using below code snippet to read some sample file using data frame and then trying to convert to rdd and apply flatmap as done earlier

```
>>> df = spark.read.text("hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/sample.txt")
>>> df.rdd.flatMap(lambda word:word.split(" ")).collect()
```

This fails with attribute Error split.

I went on to check the datatype of df.rdd and textFile using below code snippet

```
>>> type(df.rdd)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
>>> type(textFile)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
```

Both are identical.

Now when I check type of individual element of these Rdd using below code snippet. I am observing difference.

```
>>> textFile.map(lambda x:type(x)).collect()
[<type 'unicode'>]
>>> df.rdd.map(lambda x:type(x)).collect()
[<class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>]
```

Why is there discrepency

Answer (score 3):

You should convert it to list after you convert df to rdd

```
>>> textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/test/ali/sample.txt")
>>> textFile.flatMap(lambda word:word.split(" ")).collect()
['hi', 'there,', 'I', 'am', 'working', 'on', 'something', 'random.']
>>> 
>>> df = spark.read.text("hdfs://localhost:8020/test/ali/sample.txt")
>>> df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: list(x)).flatMap(lambda word:word.split(" ")).collect()
['hi', 'there,', 'I', 'am', 'working', 'on', 'something', 'random.']
```

Comment: In Scala no need to flatMap twice with spark.read. Interesting. Any ideas why? Implicit conversion is Scala I assume.